# Python not scraping all data (but it should be)

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

My code is scraping most of Reuters api data from stocks, but not everything it should. For example, "volume"; there are more than 350 stocks it should scrape from, and some it will scrape just fine, but others it will give error "data missing" when there is data (I checked myself), and some just doesn't have it (which the robot will skip it).

I've run my code in intervals of 5min and 10min, sometimes it shows up better, sometimes it is worse (not showing 80% of "volume" data when it should).

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
import pandas as pd
from decimal import Decimal, DecimalException
from collections import defaultdict
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from functools import partial
from time import sleep

NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS = 8

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.149 Safari/537.36'}

def request_getter(session, url):
    ric = url.split('/')[-1] # in case results does not contain 'ric' key
    for t in (0, 1000, 2000, 4000, 4000):
        if t:
            sleep(t)
            print(f"Retrying request '{ric}' ...", flush=True)
        data = session.get(url, headers=headers).json()
        if 'retry' not in data:
            break
    return ric, data


mapper = (
    ('Ticker', 'ric'),
    ('Beta', 'beta'),
    ('DY', 'current_dividend_yield_ttm'),
    ('VOL', 'volume'),
    ('P/L', 'pe_normalized_annual'),
    ('Cresc5A', 'eps_growth_5y'),
    ('LPA', 'eps_normalized_annual'),
    ('VPA', 'book_value_share_quarterly'),
    ('LAST', 'last')
)

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('MYCSVFILE.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    urlreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    # set max_workers to # cpu processors you have and use a requests Session for even more perofrmance
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=NUMBER_OF_CONCURRENT_URL_REQUESTS) as executor, requests.Session() as session:
        request_getter_with_session = partial(request_getter, session)
        for ric, results in executor.map(request_getter_with_session, (row[0] for row in urlreader)):
            if 'market_data' not in results:
                print(f"Missing 'market_data' key for request '{ric}'", flush=True)
                for k, v in results.items():
                    print(f'    {repr(k)} -> {repr(v)}', flush=True)
                print(flush=True)
                continue
            market_data = results['market_data']
            if 'ric' not in market_data:
                # see if any of the mapper keys are present:
                found = False
                for _, jsonDataKey in mapper:
                    if jsonDataKey in market_data:
                        found = True
                        break
                if not found:
                    print(f"Request '{ric}' has nothing recognizable in market_data:", flush=True)
                    for k, v in market_data.items():
                        print(f'    {repr(k)} -> {repr(v)}', flush=True)
                    print(flush=True)
                    continue
                # We have at least one data value present
                print(f"Results missing 'ric' key; inferring 'ric' value '{ric}' from request URL.", flush=True)
                market_data['ric'] = ric
            for dataKey, jsonDataKey in mapper: # for example, 'Ticker', 'ric'
                d = market_data.get(jsonDataKey)
                if d is None:
                    print(f"Data missing for request = '{ric}', key = '{jsonDataKey}'", flush=True)
                    d = '' if jsonDataKey == 'ric' else Decimal('NaN')
                else:
                    try:
                        if jsonDataKey != 'ric': d = Decimal(d)
                    except DecimalException:
                        print(f"Bad value for '{jsonDataKey}': {repr(d)}", flush=True)
                        d = Decimal('NaN') # Decimal class has it's own version
                data[dataKey].append(d) # add to data

table = pd.DataFrame(data)
table.index = table.index + 1
table.to_csv('CompleteData.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8', index=False)
print(table)
```

Here is a part of my csv file with stock links from Reuters:

```
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AALR3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ABCB4.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ABEV3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ADHM3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AFLT3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AGRO3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AHEB3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AHEB5.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ALPA3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ALPA4.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ALSO3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ALUP11.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ALUP3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ALUP4.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AMAR3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ANIM3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/APER3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ARZZ3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ATMP3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/ATOM3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AZEV3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AZEV4.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/AZUL4.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/B3SA3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/BAHI3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/BALM3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/BALM4.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/BAUH4.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/BAZA3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/BBAS3.SA
https://www.reuters.com/companies/api/getFetchCompanyKeyMetrics/BBDC3.SA
```

Just as an example: that AFLT3.SA has a volume of `1300`, but to my code is "data missing" (as in the moment of this post)

Comment: Maybe refactor your code to have a function to download and process a single company into a single dict; that'd be much easier to debug. Pandas will happily accept a list of records like that anyway.

Comment: How so? Sorry, I'm a newbie